# How to Export Code Formatter Settings of Delphi 2010?

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010

I searched the registry. I'd expect the settings in

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\CodeGear\BDS\7.0
```

but didn't find anything. I want to share the settings with my team. Where does Embarcadero save these?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's saved as an XML file instead of to the registry.  Look at Formatter.config in Delphi's bin\config directory.

Update:

Delphi XE allows you to [import and export formatting configurations](http://blog.marcocantu.com/blog/delphi_xe_beta_code_formatting.html) in the IDE instead of putting a specific file in a specific folder.

Comment: It's located in "AppData\Roaming\CodeGear\BDS\7.0\Formatter.config".
The bin\config seems to contain the default values for new users.